# the n should be inclusive or exclusive when using std::nth_element?

Tags: c++

Hi I have a question on the usage of `std::nth_element`.

If I want to obtain the `k-th` largest element from a vector, should it inclusive or exclusive?

```
int k = 3;
vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
std::nth_element(nums.begin(), nums.begin()+k-1, nums.end(), [](int& a, int& b){return a > b;});
int result = nums[k-1]
```

or

```
int k = 3
vector<int> nums{1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
std::nth_element(nums.begin(), nums.begin()+k, nums.end(), [](int& a, int& b){return a > b;});
int result = nums[k-1]
```

It reminds me that when we get a subarray using iterator, it should be exclusive?
for example,

```
vector<int> sub(nums.begin(), nums.begin()+k);
```

So, the `n` for `nth_element` is also exclusive?

Comment: I think you should just try running with some inputs and check what output do you get.

Comment: I don't think this is about inclusive or inclusive since the second argument to the function does not specify an endpoint of the range to be sorted but a position in the range. The first element in the vector has position 0. So if you want the 3rd largest element, you are looking for position 2, for example. Maybe this helps: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element

Comment: When iterating over a range between a begin and and end iterator, the end iterator references one past the last element.    You also need to check that `k` is valid.   In your first example, `k` with a value of `7` or more gives undefined behaviour, and a value of `8` or more gives undefined behaviour in the second case.

Comment: @kiner_shah I did. But I try both ```k-1``` and ```k```, and both of them can give me the expected result. So i am confused.

Comment: @kingwales, what is `k`? Where is it defined? What value does it have?

Comment: @kiner_shah lets assume ```k=3``` here? I updated the code.

Comment: "nth_element is a partial sorting algorithm that rearranges elements in [first, last) such that 1) the element pointed at by nth is changed to whatever element would occur in that position if [first, last) were sorted. "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the type of question that is best to figure out and understand by playing around with a bunch of examples on your own.

However, I'll try to explain why you're getting the same answer in both of your examples. As explained in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element), `std::nth_element` is a *partial* sorting algorithm. It only guarantees that, given an iterator to an element `n` as its second argument:

> All of the elements before this new nth element are less than or equal to the elements after the new nth element.

("Less than or equal to" is the default behavior if you don't pass a special comparison function.)

That means if you use `nums.begin()+k-1` in one case and `nums.begin()+k` in another case as the second argument to `std::nth_element`, then in the latter case the partial sorting algorithm will include one additional item in the sort. In that case, you are dividing the vector between larger and smaller items at a spot one index higher than in the first case. However, the (default) algorithm only guarantees that each of the items in the "small half" of the vector will be smaller than each of the items in the "large half," not that the two halves are sorted within themselves.

In other words, if you've done a partial sort through `nums.begin()+k`, there is no guarantee that `nums[k-1]` will be the next-smallest (or in your case, the next-largest) number in the entire vector.

With certain inputs, like your `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}`, or `{9, 4, 1, 8, 5}`, you do happen to get the same answers.

However, with many others, like `{1, 4, 9, 8, 5}`, the results do not match:

```
int k = 3;
vector<int> nums{1,4,9,8,5};
auto numsCopy = nums;

// First with +k - 1
std::nth_element(nums.begin(), nums.begin()+k-1, nums.end(), [](int& a, int& b){return a > b;});

// Then with only +k
std::nth_element(numsCopy.begin(), numsCopy.begin()+k, numsCopy.end(), [](int& a, int& b){return a > b;});

cout << nums[k-1]; // 5
cout << numsCopy[k-1]; // 9
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/ZMq608WEX)

Can you figure out why that is?

Also, to clearly answer your question about inclusive vs exclusive, as @Daniel Junglas pointed out in the comments, the second argument to `std::nth_element` is meant to point directly to the item you wish to be changed. So if it helps you, you can think of that as "inclusive." This is different from the third argument to `std::nth_element`, the end iterator, which is always exclusive since `.end()` points *beyond* the last item in the vector.